# filegroup in sql server doesn't map my inserted records to correct file

Tags: sql-server, filegroup

I create this file group as you can see :

Create database AdventureWorksDW

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW ADD FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2001]  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW ADD FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2002]  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW ADD FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2003]  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW ADD FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2004]  
GO
```

With these files:

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
  ADD FILE
  (NAME = N'data_2001',
  FILENAME = N'C:\FileGroupFile\data_2001.ndf',
  SIZE = 5000MB,
  MAXSIZE = 10000MB,
  FILEGROWTH = 500MB)
  TO FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2001]  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
  ADD FILE
  (NAME = N'data_2002',
  FILENAME = N'C:\FileGroupFile\data_2002.ndf',
  SIZE = 5000MB,
  MAXSIZE = 10000MB,
  FILEGROWTH = 500MB)
  TO FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2002]
GO  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
  ADD FILE
  (NAME = N'data_2003',    
  FILENAME = N'C:\FileGroupFile\data_2003.ndf',    
  SIZE = 5000MB,    
  MAXSIZE = 10000MB,    
  FILEGROWTH = 500MB)  
  TO FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2003]  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
  ADD FILE  
  (NAME = N'data_2004',
  FILENAME = N'C:\FileGroupFile\data_2004.ndf',
  SIZE = 5000MB,
  MAXSIZE = 10000MB,
  FILEGROWTH = 500MB)
  TO FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2004]
GO
```

With these partition function and schema :

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION FullOrderDateKeyRangePFN(int)  AS
  RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES 
  (  1,2,3,4  )

  CREATE PARTITION SCHEME FullOrderDateRangePScheme  AS
  PARTITION FullOrderDateKeyRangePFN  TO 
  ([Filegroup_2001],
  [Filegroup_2002],
  [Filegroup_2003],
  [Filegroup_2004],
  [PRIMARY]  )
```

And finally i created my table :

```
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[FACTINTERNETSALES_PARTITIONED] (
  [CUSTOMERPONUMBER]      [NVARCHAR](25)   NULL,
  [asl]              [int]   NULL)
  ON FullOrderDateRangePScheme  (asl)
```

I inserted 1000000 records with asl=1 into my table ,but when i run this query :

```
SELECT $PARTITION.FullOrderDateKeyRangePFN(4)  AS PARTITIONID,
       COUNT(*)                                   AS ROW_COUNT
FROM     DBO.FACTINTERNETSALES_PARTITIONED
```

it returns 1000000 records for all partitions i mean for 1 returns 1000000 and for 2 returns 1000000 and ... 
Why ?

Comment: You need to `group by` the partitionnumber. Currently, you are displaying the partition for "4" and the total number of rows in the table. Try adding `GROUP BY $PARTITION.FullOrderDateKeyRangePFN(asl)` or  `WHERE $PARTITION.FullOrderDateKeyRangePFN(asl) = 4`.

Comment: @Solarflare i changed my query to these but it returns same result :
SELECT $PARTITION.FullOrderDateKeyRangePFN(1)  AS PARTITIONID,
       COUNT(*)                                   AS ROW_COUNT
FROM     DBO.FACTINTERNETSALES_PARTITIONED

gROUP BY $PARTITION.FullOrderDateKeyRangePFN(asl)

Comment: You have no `WHERE` clause in your query so the count will be identical and the entire table is scanned. Perhaps your intention is `WHERE asl = 4` or `WHERE $PARTITION.FullOrderDateKeyRangePFN(asl) = 4` to get a row count for a specific partition.

Comment: Replace the `(1)` with `asl` too. If you add a single row into other partitions, you will get more than 1 line. Currently you get only one row as a result, because you have only rows in one partition, and that one result row is the number of rows in that one used partition (the others are empty and not listed at all). Or use the `where`-method to only display results from a specific partition.

Comment: SELECT $PARTITION.FullOrderDateKeyRangePFN(asl)  AS PARTITIONID,
       COUNT(*)                                   AS ROW_COUNT
FROM     DBO.FACTINTERNETSALES_PARTITIONED

gROUP BY $PARTITION.FullOrderDateKeyRangePFN(asl)

Comment: it works thank you i finally  add group by and replace 1 with asl